# Can typescript be used only in a few files in React project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Given there is a React project that uses plain javascript, is there a way to use typescript partially only to define models?

So, lets say there are a few models that map to server responses, can only those be defined in typescript while the rest of the project remains in javascript.

If its possible, how to do it?

Comment: Why dont you just create classes instead of a model?

Comment: hm...i am not sure i understand your question. could you please elaborate a bit more? (btw, model = classes/interfaces)

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean, why do you need typescript when you can just create a class/Interface?

Comment: as one of the ways for compile time, static type checking

Comment: You could just use `'use strict';`

Comment: i could but now i'd like to see possibilities with typescript:). there are several options one of which is `use strict`, but lets leave that one aside for now.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript can definitely be implemented gradually into an existing JS project, and I know a few people who have gone through the process on some monoliths, it can be a really boring process but usually low risk.

I'll link you straight away to this:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html

The key is to understand what your goal is, and how to set everything up properly to accommodate for it, as you go it's as simple as toggling a few settings to unblock/check work as you go.

As for your question about some files being JS and some being TS, typescript handles pure JS perfectly fine, so you can switch every file to TS and even if it's pure js there won't be an issue :)

Have a read and if you need any more help on some specifics feel free to comment

Comment: I went to a talk with one of the principal developers at Microsoft a few months back, and his viewpoint was "Why use JS when TS is just JS with some extra features... If you don't use those features there's no issue"